# Как добавить сразу 6 параметров Query при запросе retrofit?

Tags: android, запрос, retrofit, retrofit2

У меня в приложении выполняется запрос где базовыми и необходимыми параметрами согласно апи должны быть такие параметры:

```
@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset
```

все работает правильно, но я хочу добавить еще 6 параметров в запрос. Суть запроса в получении вакансий, и код вsit позволяет получить список вакансий. Дальше мне нужно добавить фильтрацию списка. Для фильтрации мне нужно добавить 6 параметров, которые в обычном режиме не будут указываться. Например, я хочу фильтровать по компаниям, и для этого я дописываю параметр:

```
@Query("company") int company
```

но при каждом запросе, мне нужно указывать этот параметр иначе не проходит запрос. И так мне нужно сделать 6 параметров. И получается что я не смогу послать запрос не указав этих параметров а это на мой взгляд не очень правильно.

Что лично я пробовал сделать или думаю что может решить мою проблему:

1. Добавить @QueryMap Map - этот вариант я так думаю мне не подойдет, потому что мне нужно 6 параметров, либо указывать три таких пары.
2. Сделать полностью новый запрос который будет вызываться при запросе на фильтрованный список - этот вариант мне кажется глупым и можно как-то более изящно сделать то что я хочу.
3. Добавлять программно параметры - это мне кажется самый рабочий вариант, но у меня часть отвечающая за базу ретрофита висит в синглтоне, и она одинакова для всех запросов в приложении, и мне не хотелось бы ее менять.
4. Найти способ типа QueryMap  только для 2+ параметров, а такой мне пока что не попадался.
5. **UPDATE** только что прочитал что можно отправлять обьект JSON в котором будет то кол-во полей которое мне нужно - моего мнения пока нет, так как не пробовал.

Я надеюсь что решение моей проблемы довольно простое и лежит на поверхности, мне поиски в сети ничего не дали кроме QueryMap. Заранее спасибо за помощь и ценные советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryMap` и есть самое простое для такого случая. Пример кода из  ([гайда](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap)):

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
// методом put добавляем сколь душе угодно пар (ключ, значение)
data.put("author", "Marcus");
data.put("page", String.valueOf(2));

// и передаём в метод апи-интерфейса
Call<List<News>> call = newsService.getNews(data);
call.enqueue(…);
```

---

```
public interface NewsService() {  
    @GET("/news")
    Call<List<News>> getNews(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
}
```

Comment: Каждый параметр имеет имя и значение - это одна пара. То есть `map.put("type",  String.valueOf(type)); `map.put("company",25));` и т.д. с остальными "элементами"

Comment: а первый блок кода я так понимаю нужно вставить в программе там где происходит выбор пунктов фильтрации и их одобрение? просто у меня запрос не пошлется я так думаю без этой map.

Comment: Да, всё так, но `Map` наполнять необязательно - может быть пустым, если нужен запрос без параметров

Comment: я вот получил исключение - Query map was null. я ведь думал что можно например отдельно указать тип и офсет а отдельно этот мап, или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Нельзя передавать 'null'. Нужен хотя бы пустой `Map` ака `Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();` `newsService.getNews(data);`. То есть инициализация `Map` обязательна.